# How to use Ember for all pages except the index page

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember project, and it's getting heavier.
I want the landing page to load faster, therefore I want to make it static HTML (without loading ember js files).
All other pages I want to have in ember.

So, I want **site.com** to serve my HTML static page (not ember), but **site.com/page1** and **site.com/page2** to serve ember pages.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use any of the server-side rendering solutions like, fastboot or prember.

Comment: I do use fastboot @GokulKathirvel, but it doesnt help me with "Largest Contentful Paint", I don't want everyone who visits the index page to load all the ember's js.

Comment: I believe "prember" solves your issue. `Prember` generates HTML during the build time for the given URLs and the generated HTML will be served initially. So your index page will be visible to the user as soon as possible without needing wait for the entire app and ember framework code to download and parse. After initial painting, Fastboot will take over the client hydartion part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [prember](https://github.com/ef4/prember)

```
ember install ember-cli-fastboot
ember install prember
```

In `ember-cli-build.js`

```
let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  prember: {
    urls: [
      '/',
    ]
  }
});
```

Configure your webserver, it should use _empty.html to respond to unknown URLs.

I've made it with the help of `.htaccess` file:

In `public/.htaccess` replace

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /_empty.html [L]
```

Troubleshooting:

I had build errors until I updated
`ember-cli-moment-shim` to `^3.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

It’s definitely possible, though the actual approach will be highly dependent on your server infrastructure. You should be able to configure the server to serve the non-Ember `index.html` and serve the Ember `index.html` for every other request.